# How to unzip only certain files that follow a specified pattern?

Tags: bash, zip

*Using bash.*

Considering I have a directory D containing the following files:

```
20170301:00.out.gz
20170301:01.out.gz
...
20170302:01.out.gz
20170302:02.out.gz

etc.
```

The files follow the pattern 'yyyymmdd:hh' (year, month, day, hour). Using bash, I would like to unzip only a couple of these files but I am not yet sure how to do so.

For one file I could of course use 'gunzip -c yyyymmdd:hh.out.gz', but hardcoding this for every single file seems a bit unnecessary...

If I would only want to unzip the files from March 7 to March 14 for example, how should I approach this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you’re using Bash, you can use its [brace expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html):

```
gunzip {20170307..20170314}*.gz
```

If you only want to view the files’ contents, add `-c` after `gunzip`.

If you’re missing files in the sequence, `gunzip` will complain about them, but it will still process all the files which *are* present in the sequence. In this case it’s also worth noting that the expansion itself will fail if the `failglob` shell option is set, but that’s not the default in Bash.

Comment: So if I am not mistaken, this command unzips all files between and including 20170307:01.out.gz & 20170314:24.out.gz?

Comment: Yes, that’s it.

Comment: And if I am not working from that current directory, can I use the command like this: gunzip dir/subdir/{20170307..20170314}*.gz

Comment: Yes, you can indeed.

Answer (score 2):

`gunzip -c` will only write the contents to standard output instead of actually unzipping them.

For your purposes:

`for a in {07..14}; do gunzip -c '201703'$a':02.out.gz'; done`

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for being unclear, but writing to standard output is what I want to do.

Comment: I have updated my answer with `-c`.

Answer (score 1):

**`find`** approach:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -regextype posix-egrep \
-regex ".*/201703(0[7-9]|1[0-4]):[0-5][0-9]\.out\.gz$" -exec gunzip {} \;
```